# Implementation between Github and VCS?

Tags: github, git-config

During commit my changes in Github I've faced this issue. I tried so many ways to connect but in the end, couldn't connect to each other. I even tried `git config --get-all user.name` .....

Run

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

to set your account's default identity.
Omit `--global` to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: no email was given and auto-detection is disabled

> git config --get-all user.name

Comment: What you posted in question is the message that git throws when you don't set your username and email.

Do as suggested by git. Set your username and email

Comment: I explained i did but doesn't work

Comment: Does `git config --global --list` return `user.name` and `user.email` properly populated?